# Having issue on linking an image, with a bitmap created before

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, bitmap

since a long time, I have tried to link an image to a Bitmap. I have already created the bitmap, I know how to put it into my image (here it is an icon from Google Maps but it changes nothing). What I want is link this icon to my bitmap called bmp. But there is an error :

> Cannot resolve symbol 'bmp'

Here is my code to help you understand my issue :

```
  private void initMarker(List<LocationModel> listData) {
        //iterasi semua data dan tampilkan markerny

        for (int i = 0; i < mListMarker.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            URL url;
            try {



                url = new URL(mListMarker.get(i).getIconImage());
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());


            } catch (IOException y) {
                y.printStackTrace();
                return ;
            }

            //set latlng nya
            LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLatutide()), Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(i).getLongitude()));
            //tambahkan markernya

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(mListMarker.get(i).getImageLocationName()).snippet(mListMarker.get(i).getIconImage()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
//.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(XXX))
            //set latlng index ke 0

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(0).getLatutide()), Double.parseDouble(mListMarker.get(0).getLongitude()));
            //lalu arahkan zooming ke marker index ke 0
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 11.0f));



        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the instance inside the try-catch statement, but reference it outside:

```
try{
    Bitmap bmp = ...
}catch(IOException e){
    //e.print....
}
//do something with bmp
```

You can't do that as it's locally created within the try-catch statement and can't be accessed outside. Do this instead:

```
Bitmap bmp = null;
try{
    URL url = new URL(mListMarker.get(i).getImageLocationName());
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
}catch(IOException e){
    //Print stacktrace and return. Otherwise you get an NPE if it fails
}
```

Declaring it outside the try-catch allows it to be accessed outside it

Comment: It seems that I don't have any errors on my code but when I launch my application, it instantly crashes. But my URL exists because I have created a Toast.makeText to show what happened so it seems that there is an error when I create an icon (on the line where I created mMap.addmarker

Comment: @nfgvnudvegnv3 if you don't add a return statement in the catch, it'll continue executing the code even if the initialization failed. There's an IOException that's thrown when you initialize bmp, meaning it's null when it reaches the add marker statement. The exception you're getting on the addMarker line is guaranteeably a NullPointerException, triggered by an IOException that prevents `bmp` from being initialized. Make sure you use `e.printStackTrace` in the catch statement to debug why it isn't initialized

Comment: Oh thanks, now I am having another issue, nothing crashes, but when I don't add icon, all markers appear, and when I add an icon, markers are invisible

Comment: I only added : 'return;' in the catch, was that what you meant?

Comment: I think in fact there is a problem in the URL, but as I said, I don't know how it can be possible because the string I pass to the URL totally exists

Comment: You have to call `e.printStackTrace` too

Comment: Ok I found the problem, but can't solve it, I have done this code in my main project, but I need to put it on an Async one. I don't know how I can do it ! Can you help me doing it please but if you don't it's not a problem !